How to use YubiKey to authenticate with WebAuthN when stolen device protection is turned on on iOS
How to use a YubiKey to authenticate with WebAuthN when stolen device protection is turned on on iOS?
Consider an iPhone with iOS 17.4.1 having Stolen Device Protection turned on. Let's try to enroll a passkey on Yubico's demo website.
Apple's default is to suggest to save a passkey in iCloud Keychain.

However, we would like to use the YubiKey to store that passkey. So let's press "Other Options".

The result is this message. When clicking "ok", the website reports that the operation has been aborted ("The request is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context, possibly because the user denied permission."). If I hold my finger on the finger print sensor, the iPhone will store the key in iCloud and enroll that key to the web site, which is not what I wanted.
Is this a bug or a feature and what is the correct procedure to approach this?
